# Python Selenium can't find Password ID

Tags: python, selenium

I'm pretty new to both Python and Selenium, and trying to create a program that can log on to a Microsence network outlet. It work fine with the open browser thing, so I open firefox and get in on the built-in API, but Selenium can't find Password ID and log on.

Anyone who can help me

**My Code look like this:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(the PATH for my Microsence modul)

psw = browser.find_element_by_id('inp0')

psw.send_keys('admin')

psw.submit()
```

**and my error code look like this:**

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="inp0"]

**And the code in the API look like this**

```
<input id="inp0" type="password" name="Q1E" maxlength="15" tabindex="2">
```

Comment: <input id="inp0" type="password" name="Q1E" maxlength="15" tabindex="2">

Comment: Make sure target element is not inside any frame/iframe.

Comment: Also, pls sure that id is assigned to only one or more than one elements by using len (browser.find_elements_by_id('inp0'))

Comment: I have now tried searching on Frame name first, with this line
"driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("f_left"))"
to be sure I am in the right Frame, and I think I'm in the right direction, but now I get the following error message:
"Could not connect because the destination computer actively refused it" 
Can the login page be made so that it's not possible to get access from a program, or how do I have to understand it

Comment: I choose to close the question now that I actually got an answer to my question, it just didn't solve my problem. so I create a new question with my current problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to wait for the page to load before you can `find_element_by_id`. Otherwise selenium won't be able to find the element you're looking for.

Check out the documentation
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: Yes you are probably right, and now I have tried to build "WAIT" into the code, so just look the code like this:

Comment: from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://x.x.x.xx')

try:

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(

        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "inp0"))

    )

finally:

    driver.quit()

psw.send_keys('admin')

psw.submit()

Comment: and get the error message: "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:" so it can't still not find my id.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(the PATH for my Microsence modul)

psw = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="inp0" and type="password"]')

psw.send_keys('admin')

psw.submit()
```

Comment: The same result, I think abdusco has got hold of something right, I just can't make it work